# setImageWithUrl is not showing the image at firstime

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimage, afnetworking

My app displays a lot of images, so I am using page control to display the images in single controller. 
User can able to see all the images by swiping.

I am using **AFNetworking** Library to show the good performance. I have used the property  `setImageWithUrl`

```
// This is myCode
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mdb.scicloudsolutions.com:8001/sites/default/files/landscape_design_1.jpg"];
[imageView setImageWithUrl:myUrl];
```

it's not showing at first time only..
When I Print url and image

```
NSLog(@"Url is .. : %@ image. is : %@",myUrl,imageView.image);
```

Response:
am receiving the url value but not image value.
It shows image is null at first time.

How to solve?

Comment: It takes time to load image initially because it is downloading from url. Put a placeholder image while image is downloading or when image is nil. Also put this code in background thread.

Comment: @Kampai Thanks for your response, As per your reply I have modified it displays placeholder image when my app launches and when i swipe my pages then only it display original url image. If does not swipe the page it shows only the placeholder image. How to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here You Set `[imageView setImageWithUrl:myUrl];` So it take time to load an Image in to ImageView.

Use  [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) Library For Better. Just Simple Download this Library From Link and Set Image like as

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: by default it's taking placeholderimage, once when i done any operation on the screen, then only it appears url image

Comment: @Jyoshna First time it take time to Download an image Then after it is Take Direct from Cache memory Also You Can find Out this Problem By 'https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage' this Link read It Carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Use following solution for this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *data
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;



NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Add these delegate methods to your view controller:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {
    if (data==nil) {
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
    }
    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection {
    connection = nil;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    // Set above image to your imageView.

    data = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    /*============= YOU ARE ON BACK GROUND THREAD ==================*/

     UIImageView *yourImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
     UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"pass your url here"]]];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        /*============= YOU ARE ON MAIN THREAD ==================*/
        yourImageView.image=img;
    });
});
```

Comment: pass your url in string Format